# How to detect IE 10+ for an onerror event

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-11, internet-explorer-10, onerror

I have a little problem with scaling SVG on IE10+.
I have this code:

```
<img src="img/logo.svg" alt="" onerror="this.src='img/logo.png'; this.onerror=null;">
```

How can I detect IE10+ for the onerror event?

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

For IE10+, use the Microsoft specific `window.msMatchMedia` feature detection:

```js
function handler(e)
  {
  if (!!window.msMatchMedia)
    {
    e.target.src = "http://stackoverflow.com/favicon.ico";
    }
  }

document.querySelector("#ie10_plus").addEventListener("error", handler, false)
```

```html
<img src="" id="ie10_plus" alt="">
```

In general, use an invalid `src` value to trigger an error. For example:

```js
document.querySelector('#foo').src="//foo";
```

```html
<img src="" width="16" height="16" onclick="javascript:this.src='http://www.stackexchange.com/favicon.ico'"/>Click Me

<img src="favicon.ico" onerror="javascript:this.src='http://stackoverflow.com/favicon.ico'" width="16" height="16"/>Despicable Me

<img id="foo" src="" width="16" height="16" onerror="javascript:this.src='http://stackoverflow.com/favicon.ico'"/>Despicable Me 2
```

**References**

- [Media query listeners (Windows)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh673551)
- [Make your HTML/JavaScript app accessible – Windows 8 app developer blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsappdev/2012/09/19/make-your-htmljavascript-app-accessible/)

Comment: Thanks you for msg. But I should detect the browser instead trying to force error on ie for loading png.